# Thermodynamic entropy vs statistical mechanical entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

In thermodynamics, we define the change in entropy of a system as:

[image]

where $T_b$ is the temperature at the *boundary* of the system.

But in statistical mechanics, we define the change in entropy of a system as:

[image]

where $T$ is the temperature of the system itself.

I am confused as both are changes in the same quantity called entropy but they don't seem to be equivalent in their definition. Could someone explain why they are defined differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because entropy is a function of state, this computation can be assumed to be performed in an equilibrium state, where it holds that $T_{b} = T$. It just makes more sense to talk about the system's temperature in statistical mechanics while referring to the thermal bath (boundaries) in classical thermodynamics.

Comment: It is not simply that we can assume an equilibrium state. The definition of entropy *requires* that the heat transfer be done reversibly, so that the system remains (infidecimally close to) an equilibrium state

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So in classical thermodynamics, are we usually assuming that the boundaries are always at the same temperature as the heat bath and also that the rest of the system is at the same temperature as the boundaries?